# Multiple values in column in csv file

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new to neo4j. I searched for my problem but couldn't find it. I have a csv file with movie name, movie type, director, producer etc.
Some of these columns contain more than one value. I want to import these values into neo4j database but I couldn't.
For example, the manufacturer column contains more than one value. When I export it to neo4j it writes 3 values as a single node. I want to show each value as different nodes.
Can you help me?

[image]

[image]

`LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM '.../FilmData.csv' AS line MERGE (n:Movie{title:line.Film_Adi_TR,released:Vizyon_Tarihi, genre:Film_Turu}) Merge(y:Yapimci{title:line.Yapimci}) Merge (n)-[:Yapimci]->(y)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split the string into individual strings (delimiter is comma) then do unwind to create the relationship one at a time. Unwind is like a "for loop".

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///FilmData.csv' AS line 
MERGE (n:Movie{title:line.Film_Adi_TR,released:line.Vizyon_Tarihi, genre:line.Film_Turu}) 
WITH n, split(line.Yapimci,",") as manufacturers
UNWIND manufacturers as m
MERGE (y:Yapimci{title: m}) 
MERGE (n)-[:Yapimci]->(y)
```

Sample:

```
Film_Adi_TR,Vizyon_Tarihi,Film_Turu,Yapimci
"The Matrix",1999,Action,"Warner Bros,Roadshow Entertainment,Silver Pictures"
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I get an error while adding the second split command. Likewise, I want to separate the directors, but I couldn't.

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM '../FilmData.csv' AS line 
MERGE (n:Movie{title:line.Film_Adi_TR,released:line.Vizyon_Tarihi, genre:line.Film_Turu}) 
WITH n, split(line.Yapimci,",") as manufacturers
UNWIND manufacturers as m
MERGE (y:Yapimci{title: m}) 
WITH n, split(line.Yonetmen,",") as director
UNWIND director as d
MERGE (yntmn:Yonetmen{title: d})
MERGE (n)-[:Yapimci]->(y)
MERGE (n)-[:Yonetmen]->(yntmn)

Comment: On line 6, add the variable "line".